# Multiple pdf file should upload

Tags: python, django

While selecting Multiple pdf file is selected but while saving only one file is saving

`views.py`

```
def pdf_upload(request):
    pdf = Client_files.objects.all()
    client = Client.objects.all()
    process = Client_Process.objects.all()
    print(process)
    print(client)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = Upload_files(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/pdf/upload/')
    else:
        form = Upload_files()
    return render(request,'uploadpdf.html',{'form':form,'pdf':pdf,'client':client,'process':process,})
```

`models.py`

```
class Client_files(models.Model):
    Date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    client_process = models.ForeignKey(Client_Process, on_delete=models.CASCADE,null=True)
    File_Name = models.FileField()
    Pages = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    Count = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    Status = models.BooleanField(default = False)

    class Meta:
        db_table : 'client_files'
```

Attached the views and models,while selecting file i can select multiple files but while uploading i can only upload one file